# How do I (simply) "do something else" to the resulting struct after the JSONDecoder().decode does it's job?

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

Very simply, I have this:

```
public struct SomeAPI: Codable {
    public let a: String
    public let b: String
    public let c: String
    public let d: String
}
```

and I of course do this ...

```
let s = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SomeAPI.self, from: data)
```

Imagine I'm decoding a few hundred of those, perhaps in an array.

Very simply, after each one is decoded, I want to run some code.

So conceptually something like ..

```
public struct SomeAPI: Codable {
    init-something() {
       super.something = magic
       print("I just decoded one of the thingies! a is \(a)")
    }
    public let a: String
    public let b: String
    public let c: String
    public let d: String
}
```

I'm afraid I have absolutely no idea how to do that, having searched much. How is it done?  It seems a shame to do it manually as a separate step.

Comment: Have you looked into implementing [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/init(from:)) yourself for the `SomeAPI` type? It sounds like that's what you're looking for — you can manually decode all of the properties by implementing that method, then add whatever code you want.

Comment: It would help to know more specifically what you want to do after decoding. I very often solve this sort of problem with a calculated or lazy property of the struct. Or perhaps you want a "reducer" that processes the decoded struct. Please provide more detail.

Comment: cheers @ItaiFerber !  Yes, I essentially want someone to tell me how to do that  :)  I want it to automatically decode (as usual) and then i can add a print statement (or whatever I wish).  {It's quite common on this site to ask "How the hell do I subclass {ie, do the initialization for} a UICollectionView ..." or such, don't you think? Because those can be tricky and non-intuitive. This is essentially such a question ...}

Comment: cheers @matt  I want it to automatically decode (as it usually does) and then I can run any code I wish, such as a print statement, a reducer as you say, a log entry, perhaps start another process, queue a pub-nub type request or a number of other scenarios. (lazy properties are indeed very useful in Decodables, but, a huge negative is that every time you make a new reference it is calculated again of course).  So yes I just want to know how to "subclass the decoding process", call "super .. the usual process!" and then run my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) documentation is a great starting point for understanding how to implement the `Encodable` and `Decodable` method requirements to add to your types — and specifically, the [Encoding and Decoding Manually](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types#2904058) section shows how to override the compiler-synthesized implementation of these methods to provide your own.

It's important to understand how the automated approach to `Codable` works, though. In a nutshell: for a type that adopts `Encodable`/`Decodable`, the compiler checks whether it's provided its own implementation of the associated method, and if not, attempts to fill it in on its own. There's no magic there: it fills in its internal state (manipulating the [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) with an implementation *as if* you had written it yourself in code.

For your example `SomeAPI` type, the generated code inside of the compiler looks *exactly* as if you had typed the following in yourself:

```swift
struct SomeAPI: Codable {
    let a: String
    let b: String
    let c: String
    let d: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case a, b, c, d
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        a = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .a)
        b = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .b)
        c = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .c)
        d = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .d)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(a, forKey: .a)
        try container.encode(b, forKey: .b)
        try container.encode(c, forKey: .c)
        try container.encode(d, forKey: .d)
    }
}
```

This only happens if you *haven't* implemented the protocol requirement yourself, though: if you have, the compiler leaves the existing implementation alone, assuming you've done exactly what you want.

This last point is relevant to your use-case, because it *sounds* like what you'd like to do is implement this type like

```swift
struct SomeAPI: Codable {
    let a: String
    let b: String
    let c: String
    let d: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        somehowCallTheCompilerSynthesizedImplementationOfThisMethod()
        /* perform some other stuff */
    }
}
```

The issue is that when you provide your own `init(from:)` implementation, the compiler *won't* synthesize anything for your type, so there's no "default" implementation to call; unfortunately, it's an all-or-nothing deal.

To do this, then, you can either:

1. Implement `init(from:)` on your types by implementing the full method, then adding whatever code you'd like, or
2. Inherit the compiler-synthesized implementation in a bit of a roundabout way: if you turn `SomeAPI` into a `class`, you can allow it to receive the default synthesized implementation, then override the synthesized implementation to do what you want (demonstrated here by moving its contents into a "dummy" parent type, then keep using `SomeAPI` as a subclass):

   ```swift
   class _SomeAPI: Codable {
       let a: String
       let b: String
       let c: String
       let d: String
   }

   class SomeAPI: _SomeAPI {
       required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
           try super.init(from: decoder)
           /* do whatever */
       }
   }
   ```

   The downside of this approach, of course, is that this changes the semantics of the `SomeAPI` type, which may very well not be what you want

Approach (1) is likely a good starting approach as it keeps the semantics of this type the same, and there are tools out there that can help automatically output code for a given Swift type (e.g. [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery)) if this gets repetitive.

Comment: AHHHHHH!  so you CAN NOT automatically get the (lets put it this way) four lines of code which decode a, b, c and d.  You'd have to manually enter those.  That's highly dangerous and ungood, since fields are commonly added/removed in the exact milieu of decoding json.

Comment: AHHHHHH! so it CAN be done, but only if you change to a class?  INCREDIBLE KNOWLEDGE